# How do I print '%' in a string that has '%s' in it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like the output to be this

> I'm using '%s' to print this out: hello!

My code:

```
print "I'm using %s to print this out: %s" % "hello!"
```

This returns an error.

Comment: While that level of detail wasn't needed for this question, "it's returning an error" isn't very useful. Show *exactly* what you tried, and *exactly* what the error was.

Comment: you could use format instead

Answer (score 6):

Put a second `%` before the literal one:

```py
print "I'm using %%s to print this out: %s" % "hello!"
```

This isn't a Python-specific solution: C's `printf`, and other analogues (such as the shell `printf`) work the same way.